# How to compile and run code written with MoveIt API?

Tags: moveit, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several tutorials on MoveIt website on C++ API like [this one](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html). I've downloaded them, built using `catkin build` and now can run those examples using `roslaunch`. But how exactly do I compile and run my own code? If I copy one of the example cpp-files to `${CATKIN_WS}/moveit_mycode/`, say `move_group_interface_tutorial.cpp`, edit a couple of lines, then what do I do next?

My take is that I shouldn't use `gcc` straightforwardly, but rather `catkin build`, which means I need a `CMakelists.txt` or something similar. Also, should I write a `.launch` file? I realize this is a very basic question, but I couldn't figure it out. I couldn't find any info on the topic, too, neither on MoveIt website nor anywhere else. I'd appreciate any help!

I'm on ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255020/how-to-compile-and-run-code-written-with-moveit-api?/) by [gsarret](https://answers.ros.org/users/29352/gsarret/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I realize this is a very basic question, but I couldn't figure it out. I couldn't find any info on the topic, too, neither on MoveIt website nor anywhere else. I'd appreciate any help!

Well .. these aren't really MoveIt specific questions, so I'm not surprised you can't find anything there: creating packages and writing nodes are considered basic skills when developing with ROS, so they are not covered by package-specific tutorials like those for MoveIt.

I would recommend you take a look at the [wiki/tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and you [pick up a book](http://wiki.ros.org/Books) (or two). [A Gentle Introduction to ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/Books/AGentleIntroductiontoROS) is free (although the author would probably appreciate it very much if you'd support him by buying a hardcopy from Amazon), and as far as I've understood from others, a good introduction to some of the basic workflows in ROS.

---

> My take is that I shouldn't use `gcc` straightforwardly

Well, you could, but it doesn't really scale very well, so avoiding it is a good idea.

> but rather `catkin build`, which means I need a `CMakelists.txt` or something similar.

Indeed. But understand that `CMakeLists.txt` are *not* something we in ROS invented. It's all just CMake (so be sure to look up [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/documentation) as well as [Catkin](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/)'s (and read/follow [some tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials))).

> Also, should I write a `.launch` file?

Only if you feel that would help make your life easier. Basically, a launch file is script that starts a bunch of nodes for you with a single command. Instead of having `N` open terminals and writing `rosrun ..` `N` times, `roslaunch` takes care of starting everything for you.

So if you have just a single node, then `rosrun $pkg $binary_name ..` might be enough. As soon as you have multiple nodes that (need to) work together, launch files would start to make sense. But it's perfectly possible to use a launch file for a single node as well.

Also:

> If I copy one of the example cpp-files to `${CATKIN_WS}/moveit_mycode/` [..]

If you have an actual Catkin workspace, then source files should not be placed at the root of it, but rather in the *source space* (`${CATKIN_WS}/src` by default). And also in a package, but that'll become clear when you read up on these things.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-18**:
PS: yes, you could place nodes anywhere, and packages and building with Catkin are not required either, but if you're just starting out I would not try to fight the system in those ways yet. Focus on understanding what is going on in 'normal' workflows, *then* start thinking about changing them.

**Comment by [gsarret](https://answers.ros.org/users/29352/gsarret/) on 2017-02-18**:
Thank you so much for a detailed answer! Everything makes a bit more sense now to me. As you've probably noticed, I'm a newbie. I'll dig into reading ROS tutorials and docs. I've read some already, just didn't realize I have to create my own package. I was aware of CMake, of course! (: Thanks again!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-18**:
No problem. Glad I could help.

For Catkin specifically btw, you might also want to take a look at [A Gentle Introduction to Catkin](http://jbohren.com/articles/gentle-catkin-intro/) by @jbohren.

It's rather defailed (so not needed per se), but good if you really want to know what is going on.